# update error-duplicate entries

Tags: updates, software-sources

The output of `sudo apt-get update` gives the error:

```
Fetched 64.4 kB in 18s (3,524 B/s)                                             
Reading package lists... Done
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_universe_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_universe_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_restricted_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it as follows:

There are duplicate entries in `sources.list`.Before proceeding further observe the error message.

It is clear that under `http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security` --`main,universe,restricted,multiverse` have duplicates.

Open terminal and run:

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Search for `http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security` and identify duplicates then keep a `#` before duplicate entries.

**Alternative** (Refer [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2455/other-software-tab-entries-in-software-updates))

Open `Software and Updates`--> `Other Software` tab

Then Remove(or just uncheck) duplicate entries.

[image: Imgur]